# Proper way to republish rejected android app

Tags: android

I am working on client project. I submitted the android app on play store from my account. It was showing on Play store. Than according to requirement i have to publish the app from client play console account. I removed app from my account and published the same app with different package name. Than it shows app rejected because of some family policy violation. I fixed this and resubmit the app. Now it taking a lot of time in reviewing the app.

I have tried to resubmit the app after editing the policies required by google.

I want to know how much time google will take to republish my app after reviewing it again.
Or How i can connect from google with any @support email.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about play store   policy and not exactly a code question.

Comment: @OscarRyz Sir this question is about delivering an app to client. There is no benefit of coding if its not helping or solving any problem.

Comment: I understand that and I do believe your question is relevant.  What I mean, is Stackoverflow is better suited for asking code questions (see [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) ). Probably asking in the Google Play support site would yield better results.

Comment: @OscarRyz Sure Sir

Answer (score 0):

It usually they review my apps within few hours... but... I feel there's something wrong inside Google and one of many emails I had from their support told me it's because there's a new review process for apps on the Family program. Well I will tell a little bit about my journey may give you some idea why you are having this problem.

We experienced this problem with 2 apps:

- First App: I received a message saying that my update was rejected because of the violation on the Family program alleging that it was crashing or giving an error (pretty generic message without any detail at all), I enter in contact on the support form and they send an email asking for me to read the terms and to update my APK number and submit again, I read the terms, I already had complied with everything so I replied saying that, we already comply with everyhting and we tested the APK and OBB installation and game play, all good, please send more details, they replied copying and pasting the same message, I once more insisted and asked for them to explain the problem, they replied asking for update my APK version and submit again, I said this will solve no crashes, please explain what is the problem and the support called Sara highlighted in the message asking to update the APK version, kind of talking with a machine that do not responded what I asked, but I updated my APK version, submitted again and... Worked. Why? For some reason they will not explain, my guess is they just marked my APK as dirty as an attempt to remove apps that the developers don't update, there's no other logical thing I can think off.
- Second App: This one I didn't had a happy end as the previous one, I tried the technique of updating the APK version 6 times, none worked, I asked help on the form (many times), they just copy and paste the message about read the Terms, I started to insist for some details, provided them with many proves that my APK+OBB files sent to Google Play are working fine, and asked for any clue about this "problem", like a device model and Android Version that they experienced it (isn't the minimum they suppose to provide us?) but after requesting this many times, for the first time the support guy called Arthur didn't copied and pasted and finally wrote an email, his answer was:

> Hi Developer,
>
> Thanks again for contacting the Google Play Team.
>
> As much as I'd like to help, due to policy, I’m not able to provide any more information or a better answer to your question. In our previous email, I made sure to include all the information available to me.
>
> If you have a different question about Google Play policies, please let me know.
>
> Regards,
>
> Arthur
>
> The Google Play Team

It means, he has no information at all about what is the problem, I've trying to solve this for 2 months, our flagship game is threatened of been removed from the store and they can't even explain why, the support team can just copy and paste a generic message without any understanding of our problem and we have no other channel to ask for help.

I'm really disappointed with Google for such poor support for developers.

Hope you can solve your problem updating your APK and submitting again, otherwise you can enter on the same loop as me.

Good luck!